# Libraries for Couchdb in C++?

Tags: c++, couchdb, cloudant

I would like to ask you if there is any library to make it easier to manage a couchdb database (in this case Cloudant) with C++.

I have read about Couchdbcpp but maybe there are some libraries which work better.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If you're happy with a "C" library, instead of C++, then this library seems to be maintained and works against CouchDB or Cloudant:

https://github.com/jubos/pillowtalk

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell couchdbcpp is not currently maintained and has not been for several years. Due to many improvements to couchdb and that Cloudant has more features than vanilla couchdb, my suggestion would be to use a C++ HTTP library to communicate with Cloudant. I am not a C++ dev so I cannot speak to the best library to use, but I found a site that looks to have a nice list of C++ libraries here:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/links/libs

Answer (score 0):

CouchDB has REST api. You can make your own easily.

I made a couchdb C++ library based on nlohmann(json library) and cpr(curl for people). It is just 200 lines. Not a full featured one. But maybe you can start from here.

https://github.com/ParkSeungwon/couchpp